# What are the necessary tools to implement targeted ads based on users information on my website product?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, mean-stack, ads

I am developing a website using the MEAN stack. My business model relies primarily on generating revenue from targeted ads which are based on user's information.
To simplify this:
User A is interested in Product XYZ. (I will have this piece of information). I will give him ads related to the product XYZ. (Facebook ads in a nutshell)
I do not know how I can implement a backend code to make this happen. Using

- Simple if...then business rules
- Available machine learning algorithms in the existing frameworks
- Or something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about what your technology stack is.
You need to collect some data from your application that has information about your visitors (which will be your features) and the ground truth about if they are interested in whatever product (you should label your visitors/observations). If you do not have the data yet, there is nothing to suggest on, so the first step for you should be collecting the data and then start analyzing it to understand if the dataset has enough quality (if not you will need to change the way you collect data, look for more and better features. this process may take a few iterations) and then what possible learners you can utilize.

Once you have dataset, I suggest existing tools for analyzing your data and employ some learners on your dataset, in Phyton or R there are very easy to use and great frameworks that will help you achieve what you want. The coding of the algorithm should be the very last thing since it will be very tough to debug and optimize your code when if you do not even know whatever the algorithm is a good fit for your data.

Comment: Thank you. The data set will be fairly simple. Every user when creating an account, will choose from a list the kind of products he's interested in. So for every user I will have that information. Then I have to map every user to the available Products that are related to his interests. When he logs in, he will find those Products. As a concept this seems easy to implement. So do you think, I should use data learners to implement that "User/Available Products mapping"?.  I am sorry but I didn't find any guidance on this subject. Thank you again for your help and time

Comment: You can build a similarity matrix between your products, so you need to know what other products (and ads realted to them) to show based on the product they claimed they are interested in. This may be enough for you. Then if you want further what you can implement is a recommender system. Here is a resourse which is not very technical yet helpful to begin with https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-built-a-recommender-system-rs-616c988d64b2 , suggest to read until end, what you look for (item-item similarity) is not in the first sections

Comment: Thank you, sir :) !